# Unable to demonstrate common fields on the same column using Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, alias, kibana, kibana-4

I am using two different indexes which are named cdr_mobile and cdr_volte that have lots of common fields. So in order to show datas on Kibana I have made an alias using two of them cdr_alias and now I am using cdr_alias in order to retieve data to Kibana.

The problem I have is, I cannot demonstrate common fields on the same column. Instead of that I am having for example, cdr_volte.startOfCharge and startOfCharge (the other thing I dont understand is here, it is using the cdr_mobile as default).

Do you have any idea how I can put the common fields on the same column ?

Thank you

Comment: Is startOfCharge a nested type? what do the documents look like in each of the indexes?

Comment: No it is not a nested type, its String.  for cdr_mobile i have startOfCharge is with value on the other hand for cdr_volte I have my cdr_volte.startOfCharge wih value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an error on mapping, In order to put same fields on the same column you must have exactly same mapping for the field for both indices.